# Multiprocessing.Process running entire script instead of just target function in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a simple example script that uses multiprocessing to execute a very simple function and return the runtimes for all parts of the process. The script is fully reproducible and looks as such:

```
import time
start_time = time.perf_counter()

import multiprocessing
print(f'Libraries loaded: {round(time.perf_counter()-start_time,2)} sec')
start_time = time.perf_counter()


def test():
    print('Sleeping 1 sec')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Done Sleeping')

print(f'Functions loaded: {round(time.perf_counter()-start_time,2)} sec')
start_time = time.perf_counter()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Multiprocessing finished in {round(finish - start_time, 2)} sec')
```

The output of the script looks as such:

```
Libraries loaded: 0.03 sec
Functions loaded: 0.0 sec
Libraries loaded: 0.0 sec
Functions loaded: 0.0 sec
Sleeping 1 sec
Libraries loaded: 0.0 sec
Functions loaded: 0.0 sec
Sleeping 1 sec
Done SleepingDone Sleeping

Multiprocessing finished in 1.12 sec

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, whilst the multiprocesses are running in parallel, they run the entire script each time as opposed to just executing the target function `test`. The script is therefore being run twice completely unnecessarily and I don't understand why.

Could someone explain this to me please?

Thanks

Comment: The entire script will be re-evaluated in a separate process iirc, and then the target is run. You need to tuck things away into functions that you don't want to run.

Comment: @Carcigenicate is there no way to create a subprocess from the main process and run off that? In some of my other scripts, I do things like read from an sql table which would cause problems if multiple processes are trying to do at he same time

Comment: @Carcigenicate This seems very sub-optimal as surely the first part of the script is completely unnecessary to run twice yet I can't stop this as I need it within the script for the process to understand what to do. I can't simply run it all from the process?

Comment: Can you not just wrap the top code in a function, then call the function in the `__main__` block? The `__main__` block will only run in the main process.

Comment: Im running into same issue, this is frustrating because the function i want to parallelize is deep within my script (at line 500) and takes 5 minutes to get there. I just want to make that function run parallel but not have to run the entire script from scratch again. @Carcigenicate 's answer will not work here.

Comment: @GunnerStone You could extract the code to run in parallel into a function in its own script, then use that as needed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah I thought about that too, the problem is the function relies on the 500 lines above it to generate variables the function uses. I thought about just saving those as function arguments to hard-disk and importing them to the isolated script. BUT the variables are pretty hefty in size (several GB) and this function is going to be run many times; so space complexity is an issue (only because SSD having limited writes).
I really wish there were not so many hoops, but Im guessing that is the con to having something as easy to use as python

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    <execute main thread here>
```

inside main thread you create the process. That new process won't call the whole script cause you only allow the **main** thread to call the whole process.

Comment: If I put everything inside the main thread then I get this error:

Comment: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'test' on <module '__mp_main__' from 'C:\\Users\\gerar\\PycharmProjects\\personal_projects\\multi.py'>

Comment: @geds133, can you provide some code?